# How to calculate the power consumption of a VM?

Tags: cloudsim

Respected researchers, i want to calculate the power consumed by the virtual machines of a physical server in a cloud datacenter. 
 please help me i will be very thankful for this appreciation.

Comment: respected alhelal,  i could not understand your suggestion please explain it one more time

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
     * The cost of each byte of bandwidth (bw) consumed.
     */
    protected double costPerBw;

    /**
     * The total bandwidth (bw) cost for transferring the cloudlet by the
     * network, according to the {@link #cloudletFileSize}.
     */
    protected double accumulatedBwCost;

    // Utilization
    /**
     * The utilization model that defines how the cloudlet will use the VM's
     * CPU.
```

This segment are taken from [Cloudlet.java](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/Cloudlet.java).line 212. This may be helpful.

Or, as you set each VM properties you can calculate the power consumption.

```
//VM description
            int vmid = 0;
            int mips = 250;
            long size = 10000; //image size (MB)
            int ram = 2048; //vm memory (MB)
            long bw = 1000;
            int pesNumber = 1; //number of cpus
String vmm = "Xen"; //VMM name
```

This segment taken from [CloudSimExample3.java](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/examples/CloudSimExample3.java) line 64

Answer (score 0):

CloudSim Plus has a built-in feature to compute VM's power consumption.
The method below shows how to use such a feature. You can get the complete example [here](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/power/PowerExample.java).

```
private void printVmsCpuUtilizationAndPowerConsumption() {
    for (Vm vm : vmList) {
        System.out.println("Vm " + vm.getId() + " at Host " + vm.getHost().getId() + " CPU Usage and Power Consumption");
        double vmPower; //watt-sec
        double utilizationHistoryTimeInterval, prevTime = 0;
        final UtilizationHistory history = vm.getUtilizationHistory();
        for (final double time : history.getHistory().keySet()) {
            utilizationHistoryTimeInterval = time - prevTime;
            vmPower = history.vmPowerConsumption(time);
            final double wattsPerInterval = vmPower*utilizationHistoryTimeInterval;
            System.out.printf(
                "\tTime %8.1f | Host CPU Usage: %6.1f%% | Power Consumption: %8.0f Watt-Sec * %6.0f Secs = %10.2f Watt-Sec\n",
                time, history.vmCpuUsageFromHostCapacity(time) *100, vmPower, utilizationHistoryTimeInterval, wattsPerInterval);
            prevTime = time;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```